# Error in processing code for saving dataframe into Hbase- spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to run the code from this link:

https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_save_the_dataframe

But I am getting the error too many arguments, am I missing something ? Because I did not modify the code from the link at all.

If there are any down-voting , please explain or comment ,so that we know the issue on what we are doing wrong.

```
case class HBaseRecord(col0: String,col1: Boolean,col2: Double,col3: Float,col4: Int, col5: Long,col6: Short,col7: String,col8: Byte)


scala> object HBaseRecord {def apply(i: Int, t: String): HBaseRecord = {
 |   val s = s"""row${"%03d".format(i)}"""
 |   HBaseRecord(s, i % 2 == 0, i.toDouble, i.toFloat,  i, i.toLong, i.toShort,  s"String$i: $t",      i.toByte)
 | }
 | }
<console>:27: error: too many arguments for method apply: (i: Int, t: String)HBaseRecord in object HBaseRecord
HBaseRecord(s, i % 2 == 0, i.toDouble, i.toFloat,  i, i.toLong, i.toShort,  s"String$i: $t",      i.toByte)
         ^
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use phoenix for reading/writing RDD/DF from/to Hbase, for more details: https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html

Comment: Thanks satish, we don't have phoenix environment,I was hoping for a work around and easy way to automate this. Thanks for sharing anyway.

Comment: I don't think there is a straight solution for saving/reading dataframe to hbase, you need to convert df as rdd then save it as saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset. Here is the example, have a look. http://cjcroix.blogspot.com/2015/10/pyspark-hbase-and-spark-streaming-save.html